# Singly Linked List operations in C++ with complexity O(1)

Tags: c++, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

I am required to make a linked list which can undergo three operations.
All three of these operations must have O(1) complexity.

The operations in question are:

- Add to tail
- Remove from head
- Return middle node

The node structure being used is as followed:

```
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* link;

        node(int input) {
            data = input;
            link = NULL;
        } 
    };
```

For removing the head, I have achieved O(1) by just having the usual reference to the head node

```
    if (head != NULL) {
         if (head->link == NULL) {
            delete head;
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
         }
         else {
            node* temp = head;
            head = head->link;
            delete temp;
         }
    }
```

For adding to the tail, I have achieved O(1) by having a reference to the tail node

```
    if(head != NULL) {
         tail->link = new node(input);
         tail = tail->link;
    }
    else {
         head = new node(input);
         tail = head;
    }
```

My issue is with returning the middle node. I know how to do this with traversing the list but that means it will have O(n) complexity. My main thought was if I keep a reference to the current position of the middle node I could track it at all times. This works with the Add to tail function because I can just move the middle node forward accordingly. It doesn't work, however, with removing the head as there is no way I can keep moving the middle reference backwards due to it having to be a singly linked list.

I have been assured that it is possible to do this in O(1) and have been hinted that the reason it can be done is because these are the only three operations that the list will ever undergo and there is therefore a pattern for the middle node to follow.

I can't think of any way this can be done short of keeping a reference to every node from the head to the middle node as a bare minimum but have been told that I do not need to do that to achieve O(1).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't work, however, with removing the head as there is no way I can keep moving the middle reference backwards

Good thing you don't have to move the middle backwards, then! Removing the head can only make the middle go forward.

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid.
I got way to close to it and was overthinking it wayyyy too much.
Thanks for that